# Powershell crashes on startup

Tags: powershell

Ok, my powershell crashes on startup.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at System.Management.Automation.CoreTypes.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.EarlyStartup.<>c.<Init>b__0_1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Any help? It just bassicly crashes. Nothing else. Please i need it.

Comment: Do you also get the error if you execute `powershell -NoProfile` in cmd?

Comment: @Thomas yes, still crashes.

Comment: What version of PowerShell and (assuming you're on Windows), which exact operating system version?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i don't know how to check it on cmd, but i have Windows 10

Comment: @NightShadeTVN Execute `where powershell` in cmd. Which path does it return? Then follow that path and right click on that executable. Which file/product/build version does it show on the details tab?

Comment: What @Thomas said, alternatively use `wmic datafile where name='c:\\path\\to\\powershell.exe' get version` from cmd to get the file version

Comment: @Thomas it gives me "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
File Version is : 10.0.18362.1

Comment: @NightShadeTVN That looks ok. Did you install something related to PowerShell or .NET by yourself? Did you remove anything related to it? Any registry changes? Any Windows "debloating" scripts?

Comment: You always can install Windows Management Framework 5.1 to update your powershell version to 5.1.